# Добавление анимации в SVG через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```
var biggeranimation = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#boomcirc');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'r');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('values', '1;30');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('dur', '2s');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('repeatCount', '1');
document.getElementById('boomie').appendChild(biggeranimation);
```

Нужно добавить анимацию с помощью JavaScript примерно так... Добавить элемент, над которым производятся действия, получилось, но он не анимируется. В чём подвох?

Comment: Возможно, лучше использовать [`setAttributeNS(null, …)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2156308/4267982).

Answer (score 1):

Было бы замечательно увидеть еще и код SVG, над которым производятся манипуляции. Судя по тому, что элемент `animate` анимирует радиус, то зачем строчка

```
biggeranimation.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#boomcirc');
```

мне непонятно. Если её удалить и добавить анимацию к имеющемуся элементу, то всё работает как надо.

```js
var biggeranimation = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');

biggeranimation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'r');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('from', '1');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('to', '30');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('dur', '10s');
biggeranimation.setAttribute('repeatCount', '1');

document.getElementById('boomie').appendChild(biggeranimation);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='20' fill="black" id="boomie"></circle>
</svg>
```